# How to change the color render setting for anchor in a css file?

Tags: html, css

I'm a server-end python programmer, and have very few knowledge about css.

Recently I was using gitbook to write our doc-sites.
Everything was OK, except when I'm using anchors in the `md` files.
The content wrapped in the anchor tag will be show in blue. Which isn't good.

I wanna disable this blue color rendering, then I did some search and find the page was influenced by a file named `style.css`.
There is only 1 extremely long line in this file. I searched `blue` in it, nothing.
And then I searched `anchor` in it. I got:

```
fa-anchor:before{content:"\f13d"}.
.anchor{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;display:block;padding-right:6px;padding-left:30px;margin-left:-30px}
.anchor:focus{outline:0}
```

Is this `fa-anchor:before{content:"\f13d"}.` thing which influenced the anchored content rendering? How to disable its effect?

If it isn't, what key-word should I searching in the `css` file for anchored contnet rendering?

PS: In this question the `anchor` means syntaxs in html like `<a href='#stash_save'> save </a>`

Comment: `fa-anchor:before{content:"\f13d"}` it means the icon will be added before the HTML element and generated icon using `unicode` won't be part of DOM.

Comment: what is the class you are using for `<a>` tag? would be good if you can paste some rendered `HTML code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zen `fa-anchor:before{content:"\f13d"}` this code means the generated icon using `unicode character` won't be part of DOM.

By default when `<a>`element apply by default color turns into `blue color` you have to find the class if any applied on `<a>` tag. otherwise you can change the color using `<a href="#" style="color:#535353">`. using inline CSS here just for reference.

You can make a specific class for `<a>` tag.

Hope it solve your problem.  check the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ganabezufu/1/edit) also.

Comment: inline css is good, can this `#535353` be replaced with words like `grey` or `white`?

Answer (score 0):

add `color: red;`

to the end of

```
.anchor{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;display:block;padding-right:6px;padding-left:30px;margin-left:-30px}
```

and see if it modifies the color.